# Looking for Lommel-Weber function on scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm looking to compute a Lommel-Webber function which is related to 1F2. I see that scipy.special.hyp1f2 is flagged as deprecated. What should I use?

Comment: one option could be to use the implementation of the function in [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html#hyp1f2) library

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll check. I also saw in Abramowitz and Stegun a relationship between Lommel-Weber and Struve, and Struve functions are ufunc implemented. Thanks,